# Codeigniter Datatable Union and Order by

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I'm using codeigniter and for listing using jquery datatable.In codeigniter i used datatable library and i have to use order by and union in my sql query

mysql query look like

```
SELECT date_format(cp_cuspaydate, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') as transdate,cp_cusaccno as accno,'Purchase' as particulars,cp_cusamount as amount,
cp_qty as crqty,'-' as drqty, '' as blanceqty
FROM chf_customerpayments
WHERE cp_cusid = 22
UNION
SELECT date_format(credm_reqdate, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') as transdate,credm_accno as accno,'Redeem' as particulars,'-' as amount,
'-' as crqty,credm_weight as drqty, '' as blanceqty
FROM chf_customerredeemrequest
WHERE credm_cusid = 22 AND credm_status !=2
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(transdate,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') asc;
```

I need to generate datatable, for that i tried following code

```
$this->datatables
              ->select("date_format(cp_cuspaydate, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') as transdate,cp_cusaccno as accno,'Purchase' as particulars,cp_cusamount as amount,
cp_qty as crqty,'-' as drqty, '' as blanceqty", false)
              ->from('chf_customerpayments')
              ->where('cp_cusid',$this->session->userdata('user_id'))
              ->union('chf_customerredeemrequest')
              ->select("date_format(credm_reqdate, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') as transdate,credm_accno as accno,'Redeem' as particulars,'-' as amount,
'-' as crqty,credm_weight as drqty, '' as blanceqty", false)
               ->where('credm_cusid = '.$this->session->userdata('user_id').' credm_status !=2');
              echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

But there is no union function in datatable library. How to do this to generate datatable for my query.Please help any one, thanks in advance

Comment: can u try this ->from('chf_customerpayments UNION chf_customerredeemrequest')

Comment: i have tried this but no use.It will Cobain all the fields into single select

Answer (score 1):

Slightly complex queries (such as this one) are not possible with codeigniters active record, specially when the case of nesting, unions, etc comes in.

Use `$this->db->query("...");` to  run this query "the old fashioned way".

Be sure to escape your data through `$this->db->escape(variable)`

Primarily in this case, the active record of codeingiter is not designed to have multiple "selects" in one query. which means even if you add the "union" keyword (as a comment suggested) it will group together all the "selects" into one statement.

Comment: Is it possible to query in codeigniter active records and use with datatable library

Comment: The final result of using $this->db->query and using active records is almost the same. So if it is possible to generate through active records, it should be possible to generate through $this->db->query. Although I do not believe their is any function that directly maps to the datatable structure. You will have to do that yourself.

Comment: @VinothKumar your current conundrum is the exact reason why i moved to [laravel] (http://www.laravel.com) from codeigniter. Laravel's active record `Eloquent` is far more powerful than Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do both queries separately $query1 & $query2.
Then merge the result sets like this:

$union = array_merge($query1, $query2);